How to verify written solana program buffer account data and uploaded program build file with checksum?
I'm attempting to verify if the file in the program buffer account matches the content of the build file. I used solana account  to retrieve data from the buffer account, calculated the SHA sum, and compared it with the SHA sum of the uploaded build file, but the results aren't matching as expected.
commands used
$ cat ./target/deploy/test_build.so | shasum -a 256 | awk '{print $1}'   

$ solana account <account-address> | shasum -a 256 | awk '{print $1}'  


I am not familiar with checksum, but if you want to verify solana programs, check out the verifiable build CLI tool.
You can use the anchor CLI for building verifiable programs and documented here
Building
anchor build --verifiable

Verifying
anchor verify -p <lib-name> <program-id>

My guess would be that when you call solana account show <buffer-account-address>, the information you are returning is a parsed base64 encoded string as seen if you change the output to json solana account <address> --output json
